# fatal error C1900: Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20060201' and 'P2' version '20050411'

Tags: linker

I compile my project with VIsual Studio 2005 Express Edition, and get this linking error. Can anyone suggest how to solve that?

Answer (score 7):

I downloaded VS2005 Service Pack 1 from Microsoft, installed it and it fixed the problem.

Comment: This worked for me too but I had trouble installing SP1 for 2005. I think this primarily because I had also installed VS2010 on my machine and SP1 updated was unable to find out which version to update (..oh microsoft!). At the end I used windows Update utility to keep finding all updates and it first discoovered SP1 for VS2010 and installed and later discovered SP1 for VS2005 and installed it. After that my error went away.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN: [Fatal Error C1900](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks07be9f(VS.80).aspx) says:

"Tools run in various passes of the compiler do not match. *number1* and *number2* refer to the dates on the files. For example, in pass 1, the compiler front end runs (c1.dll) and in pass 2, the compiler back end runs (c2.dll). The dates on the files must match and if they do not, reinstall and use the current version of each tool."

Go to Add/Remove Programs, select Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition, click Change/Remove, then perform a repair.

Answer (score 2):

That exact question is asked and answered at http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1512436&SiteID=1.

Try re-installing.  It appears to be an install of the wrong service pack.